Crash due to 'libswift_Builtin_float.dylib' with Xcode 16 beta 6 build on iPadOS 17.6.1

During our app upgrades and backward compatibility tests, we've noticed that the app built on Xcode 16 beta 6 crashes on the iPads running iPadOS 17.6.1.
Here is the full error log:
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: DYLD 1 Library missing
Library not loaded: /usr/lib/swift/libswift_Builtin_float.dylib
Referenced from: <5ABE5504-A64E-37F0-A7C9-D653A5755900> /Volumes/VOLUME/*/<myapp>.app/Frameworks/AppCoreFramework.framework/AppCoreFramework
Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/libswift_Builtin_float.dylib' (no such file), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/swift/libswift_Builtin_float.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/libswift_Builtin_float.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

I've tried to find any solution, but I've not come across anything that would solve this for us.
Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Downvote? without any explanation of it? This is epitome of uncalled behavior on this forum!

Answering my own question here, for anyone who might face similar issue and don't get any responses:

I ended up adding libswift_Builtin_float.tbd to the Link Binary With Libraries in the Build Phases of the Target
Then setting the Status to Optional instead of Required.

After that, building the project and running it on iPadOS 17 devices, fixed the backward compatibility crash.
